# Can permission sets shorten the access provided by profiles?

Tags: permissions, permission-sets

Can permission sets shorten the access provided by profiles?

I am learning the topic on [the](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/data_security/units/data_security_fields?trailmix_creator_id=00550000006yDdKAAU&trailmix_id=prepare-for-your-salesforce-platform-developer-i-credential) Trailhead. And what I know from there that no, permission sets can not shorten the access provided by profiles, they can only expand it. For example, here :

> Remember, a permission set is for expanding a user’s access to fields that are restricted in their profile.

But I am asking this because I encountered in the same unity the following (all that described further was achieved using permission sets):

> We’ve prevented them from changing the Hire By date or the name of the hiring manager, but they can see that information. And they don’t need to know the pay rate for the position, so we’ve removed both their Read and Edit access for those fields.

So, is it possible to impose restrictions (which would shorten the access provided by the profile) using the permission sets? Or does in the example above the permission sets did not shorten the profile access, but just did not expand it and the author of the unit considers it as a restriction imposition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first statement is correct.

> a permission set is for expanding a user’s access to fields that are restricted in their profile.

Meaning that, in the example, the permission sets did not shorten the profile access, but just did not expand it and the author of the unit considers it as a restriction imposition.

They could made it clearer on the Trailhead, but the Standard User Profile (which is used on the example) does not have access to any custom objects by default